# How to unbind Service from different class in which it has not been binded

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating a music player app in which I've created a `Service` for playing tracks.

For controlling a player I'm using `bindService()`

Below is the code, I'm using ServiceController class to bind(inside inistService()) and unbind(inside releaseService()):

```
public class ServiceController {

    MusicServiceAidl aidlObject;
    CallMService serviceConnection = new CallMService();
    Context context;

    public ServiceController(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    class CallMService implements ServiceConnection {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
            aidlObject = MusicServiceAidl.Stub
                    .asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Service Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName paramComponentName) {
            aidlObject = null;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Service Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void initService() {
        try {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setClassName("com.example.async",
                    com.example.async.PlayTrack.class.getName());
            boolean ret = context.bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Service bound with " + ret,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "initService(): " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void releaseService() {
        context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
        serviceConnection = null;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service Released",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public String getTrackName() throws RemoteException{
        return aidlObject.getTrackName();
    }

    public String getAlbumName() throws RemoteException{
        return aidlObject.getAlbumName();
    }

    public String getArtistName() throws RemoteException{
        return aidlObject.getArtistName();
    }

    public void playPreviousTrack() throws RemoteException{
        aidlObject.playPreviousTrack();
    }

    public void playNextTrack() throws RemoteException{
        aidlObject.playNextTrack();
    }

}
```

To call this binding class, I'm using:

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(getApplicationContext());
serviceController.initService();
serviceController.releaseService();
```

The problem is I'm trying to stop the service from a different class, i.e. I want to call `releaseService` from a different class. But obviously, it gives `IllegalArgumentException`.

**EDIT:**
When I run below code:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                Class.forName("com.example.async.PlayTrack"));
        stopService(intent);
        serviceController.releaseService();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Listing.java", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(Listing.this,
                "Listing->onBackPressed: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

I get following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.example.async.classes.ServiceController$CallMService@40547298
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Bind and unbind using the application context not the activity context. You can get application context in an activity using `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: tried.. In this class constructor I used `this.context = c.getApplicationContext();` But still not working...tell me if I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is this "class" an activity? If not, how are you creating instances of this "class" that binds to the service? Show more code please.

Comment: No class is not an `Activity`. 
Code updated and thanks for helping

Comment: I see no reason why another class can't call `serviceController.releaseService()`. Please post the logcat error and stacktrace when you get the Exception.

Comment: code updated with my calling function and exception I'm getting

Comment: Please post the stacktrace too so we can see where the error occurs.

Comment: how does the variable `serviceController` (the one that is used in `onBackPressed()`) get initialized? This must be a reference to the same object as the one you used to call `initService()`.

Comment: That is my question. `serviceController` is not the same used in `initService()`. `initservice()` is being called from different Activty. How can I use that reference to stop the service.

Comment: Pass the reference from one activity to another or store it in a globally accessible place (ie: a static member variable in some class).